# Auto changing lock screen backgrounds from my facebook photos

Tags: lock-screens

So I just purchased a oneplus one and am switching over from a windows phone. One of the features I like on the windows phone is the ability to auto change my facebook photos as my lock screen background. Basically within the settings, I can choose the facebook app, pick which albums I want, and then my lock screen background gets automatically set to a new photo from those albums every few hours. Anything like this possible on android? I don't remember it being possible when I last used Android.

Thanks

Jakub

Answer (score 0):

Sync your Facebook album to your phone and then use a live wallpaper such as Photo Album. Finally, set the live wallpaper to be your lock screen. Not intuitive, but hey, that's the flexibility of Android! :)